# Explanation of Risk Proxies in FX

Tags: fx

I came across the following line in an article: "Risk proxies traded heavy despite the rally in rates helping the S&P500 to its 4th consecutive green day." I would like to understand what are the risk proxies referring to.

Comment: Why do you think that "rates" here refers to FX rather than to interest rates?

Comment: The rates here should imply interest rates. However, the "risk proxies" is probably referring to FX. I am unsure on which ccy pair its referring to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Risky things (including currencies) are sometimes called *risk proxies*, safe things are *risk havens*. (USD and to some extent JPY, CHF are said to go up in times of trouble (safe haven currencies), EM currencies to go down when there are economic problems, they are risk proxies.

Another example: Junk bonds are risk proxies, US Treasuries are risk havens. etc. etc. Each class of assets has some assets that are considered riskier than the others.

"traded heavy" means it went down in price at least to some extent (maybe not a lot), it is not the same as "heavy trading" (which means large volume of buys/sells) .